# How can I get min value of Y for each value of X?

Tags: python, pandas, math, pandas-groupby

I have two lists X and Y.

```
X = [0.034, 0.026, 0.028, ...]
Y = [0.0099, 0.0065, 0.0061, ...]
```

I want to get min value of Y for each value of X. I tried with groupby approach. I need to get points on the border. which are marked in black in the figure below. I have X and Y coordinate for all the points.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `groupby` with `min()`:

```
import pandas as pd

# two y values for 0.034 and 0.026

X = [0.034, 0.026, 0.028, 0.034, 0.026]
Y = [0.0099, 0.0065, 0.0061, 0.1, 0.000001]

df = pd.DataFrame({'x': X, 'y': Y})

       x         y
0  0.034  0.009900
1  0.026  0.006500
2  0.028  0.006100
3  0.034  0.100000
4  0.026  0.000001

df.groupby('x')['y'].min()

x
0.026    0.000001
0.028    0.006100
0.034    0.009900
Name: y, dtype: float64
```

As you deal with floating point numbers, you might want to do a `groupby` with rounded numbers (e.g. 5 digits):

```
df.groupby(df['x'].round(5))['y'].min()
```

That will give 8018 `x-y` pairs using the dataset you provided.

Comment: I tried using this approach but it is giving me points which are not on the border. I only need points which are on the border (like one marked in black). This group by will give each value of Y as all the points have X and Y coordinate value.

Comment: @Upriser: Then you should provide some representative input, otherwis eit is hard to help.

Comment: What kind of alternative input you want.

Comment: @Upriser: One that illustrates  your actual issue. Show a real but minimal example, show what you have tried, which output you got and why it is not sufficient. Just from the description it sounded like that's what you need as the minimal value should be at the border at the same time (I also still fail to come up with a case where the minimal `Y` value is not at the border - could you provide such an example?!)

Comment: I have used the same approach of groupby as you suggested but when I'm trying that approach it is giving me same original result. There is no change in output. The objective is to get the all the points which are on the border. I'm uploading another image. I need to get points along that edge.

Comment: @Upriser: If you get the same output as you provide as input, you might not have any duplicate values in `x` (e.g. due to floating point numbers). Could you check `df.x.nunique()` and compare it to `df.shape`?!

Comment: @Upriser: Yes, but how does `df.x.nunique()` compare to `df.shape[0]`?

Comment: @Upriser: As the two numbers differ, the output should not be identical to the input. But at this state it is hard to help further, as your input is unclear; if you provide a representative dataset, we can help (the plot does not help much, we need actual numbers).

Comment: Is it okay if I share a google drive link to you for that data?

Comment: @Upriser: I don't know either. However, as mentioned it is hard to help without it. Given the information you provide the above solution should work, as the points on the black line correspond to the minimum `Y` for a given `X`; that's exactly what we calculate.

Comment: @Upriser: seems it is a floating point issue; see my edited answer for one option how to deal with it.

Comment: @Upriser: Glad to hear! That's why showing the real data is so important :)

Comment: Next time I will do that. Thanks a lot for help.

Comment: @Celb your solution is also working correctly. But the thing is I need to round it to 4 decimals thats it.

Answer (score 1):

This is one way in  Python to get min values ..
See the as an example

```
list1, list2 = [123, 223, 154, 235], [456, 700, 200]
print "min value element : ", min(list1)
print "min value element : ", min(list2)
```

When we run above program, it produces following result −

```
min value element :  123
min value element :  200
```

Pandas solution as stated in above answer:

```
df.groupby('x')['y'].min()
```

Comment: I need to get multiple values from each list as I need points which are on the border